# Efficiently Extract multiple log values using sed

Tags: sed, extract

I almost have a working code of what I need, I just don't quite know all the syntax.
I apologize for my previous not understandable post so I will rewrite my request, hopefully easier to understand.
I have a message log of several hundred lines. In this log, there are two lines that I am concerned with extracting data from.
The two log lines in the log are:

```
2357: 11-Feb-2019 09:51:22 (low) [] 1369 floating point MIPS (Whetstone) per CPU
2358: 11-Feb-2019 09:51:22 (low) [] 5388 integer MIPS (Dhrystone) per CPU
```

I am extracting the values 1369 & 5388 from those two lines. The code I have created is:

```
proc=( $(boinccmd --get_messages | sed -n 's/\s*integer MIPS (Dhrystone) per CPU//p' | awk -F\  '{print $6}') )
printf "%s"${proc}"\n"
proc=( $(boinccmd --get_messages | sed -n 's/\s*floating point MIPS (Whetstone) per CPU//p' | awk -F\  '{print $6}') )
printf "%s"${proc}"\n"
```

But this sends sed out on a double fishing trip.

Is there a way I can make this more efficient by either using a different process or by having sed double-up and look for two things at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: "I need to find a simpler way" Please elaborate in which way simpler.

Comment: Please show your results for the shown sample input, highlight the "unneeded front end stuff". Provide more sample input and its output, including input which gives satisfactory result.

Comment: Do you need a simpler solution or  are you still at "does not work"?

Comment: Dou you need the regex part solved or the moving into variables part? Those are two different problems. Please focus this quesiton on one of them, then ask a separate one for the other.

Comment: Please clarify the desired result. How should the output of the sed part (or the write-to-variabls part) look like?

Comment: You will probably soon get many comments on "Why not use <other tool>?" Please give reasons for your choice of sed.

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch - I am using sed because it's just something I know at the moment. I've seen it used in the past... I'm just a novice programmer.

Answer (score 2):

How about awk:

```
$ awk '{print $6}' file
1369
5388
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the output I need in a variable. The two lines I showed are just two lines out of a thousand line log file...So I have been able to get sed searching to get the info from the lines(s) that I need. I tried to tie in awk'{print $6}' ${proc} …. I guess I need sed to provide the 6th character of ${proc}...

Comment: @WesZ no, you don't. You never need sed when you're using awk. If you edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output and a clearer explanation of your requirements then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If `Procedural Text Edit` is an option:

```
forEach line {
    ifElse (or 
             (contains cs "floating point MIPS (Whetstone) per CPU")
             (contains cs "integer MIPS (Dhrystone) per CPU")) {        
        select (afterN char 4) { remove }    
    } {
        remove
    }
}
```